# Save object states on web service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

Since few days, I'm looking for an answer at my problem and I'm going off the rails. So I ask my question here, maybe someone will have an idea.

I created a WCF webservice with many methods. I would like to save some datas in an object on the webservice during the call of the first method and reuse them when the client call a second method.

For example :

```
public class Toto : IToto
{
        private List<Hardware> hwList = new List<Hardware>();

        public void addHardware(Hardware hw) {
                hwList.Add(hw);
        }

        public void getHardwareList(out List<Hardware> list)
        {
                list = hwList;
        }
}
```

I would like, when I call the addHardware method, the list keep in memory all the Hardware objects I putted in it. Then, when I call getHardwareList, retreive all Hardward objects putted in list before.

The problem is, after each call, my list is reinitialized, and is empty.

I found a lot of informations about "PerSession" in InstanceContextMode but it doesn't work. When I force the ServiceContract to be SessionMode.Required, a lot of trouble appears with basicHttpBinding. I tried to change it to wsHttpbinding but without success.

My final question is : is it possible to save the instance of my list without save its state in database and withtout serialize it in the XML request/answer.

It doesn't matter if each instance of the webservice created on client has its own list, because that is what I want. So the first instance of the webservice will have its instance of the list, and the second instance will have another instance of the list.

Anybody can help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the list per client or per service? If the answer is per client then you need some binding which support either WCF session (not possible with `BasicHttpBinding`) or you must degrade WCF service to use ASP.NET session (by using AspNetCompatibility) or you must add your own mechanism. If the answer is per service (all clients will access the same list) you should use `InstanceContextMode.Single` and handle synchronization in your methods (one client can add HW to list in the same time other client want read list).

Comment: I want to use on list per client (instance of webservice). Do you have any hints about how do that you explained above ?

Comment: Maybe I can use a static HashMap which will give to each instance its datas but I need an unique ID. Someone knows an unique ID send to webservice for each request ?

Comment: You don't need unique ID per request but per client. You can use `Guid`.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are global to all users, you can use static properties or singleton pattern to hold your objects around in memory, just make sure to handle sync problems.

If your objects are user bound and you want to avoid using sessions, you need to build a global dictionary to map between user to it's objects.

In both cases there is a scaling issue if you are using a web garden or clustered servers.

Cheers,

Gilad

Comment: I'm looking to use sessions in my webservice, but I don't find any documentation to make this work.

Comment: [ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://IESServices.org/", ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode= InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public abstract class BaseServiceLibrary:BaseLayer

Comment: This attribute, should be on your service object with some form of http binding.

Comment: Microsoft has a great documentation about web session support in WCF here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx